# Haskell - readFile catch exception

Tags: haskell, exception, io, readfile

I am trying to read file in Haskell with exception catching but cant get working.
The code looks like:

```
     module Main where
    import System.Environment
    import System.IO
    import System.Exit

    main = do
        x:xs <- getArgs
        case length(x:xs) of
            2 -> do catch (readFile x)
                        (\_ -> do   putStrLn ("Error on reading file: " ++ x) 
                                    getLine
                                    exitWith ExitSuccess)
            _ -> do putStrLn ("Run this way: ./projekt inputFile RE") >>
                exitFailure
```

And I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO String
                              -> (ExitCode -> IO a)
                              -> ExitCode
                              -> IO String'
       against inferred type `IO ()'
In the expression:
    putStrLn
      ("Error on reading file: " ++ x) getLine exitWith ExitSuccess
In the expression:
    do { putStrLn
           ("Error on reading file: " ++ x) getLine exitWith ExitSuccess }
In the second argument of `catch', namely
    `(\ _ -> do { putStrLn
                    ("Error on reading file: " ++ x) getLine exitWith ExitSuccess })'
```

Can you give me a hint?
Thanks

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Exception.html#5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `>>` (or an extra `do`) on line 13:

```
_ -> do putStrLn ("Run this way: ./projekt inputFile RE") >>
```

should be:

```
_ -> do putStrLn ("Run this way: ./projekt inputFile RE")
```

or:

```
_ -> putStrLn ("Run this way: ./projekt inputFile RE") >> exitFailure
```

Full code:

```
main = do
l@(x:xs) <- getArgs
case length l of
    2 -> do catch (readFile x) $ \_ -> do
            putStrLn $ "Error on reading file: " ++ x
            getLine
            exitWith ExitSuccess
    _ -> do putStrLn $ "Run this way: ./projekt inputFile RE"
            exitFailure
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation.

Although your code looks ok as you have pasted it, the error message suggests that maybe the `getLine` and `exitWith ExitSuccess` are indented further than the `putStrLn` above. Perhaps this is a spaces -v- tabs issue?